# Changing servers, want to make sure Googlemail doesn't go down

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, email-server, g-suite

We are currently moving from one server to another.

I'm new to DNS and server admin which isn't ideal I know!  This is how our **current working domain** is set up for email with Google apps:

http://www.intodns.com/scirra.com

In preparation for moving server and changing nameserver I've created this zone on zoneedit (the current nameserver isn't with zoneedit):

[image]

And this is what the DNS looks like on the new server:

[image]

What I would like to know is when I point the domain to the new nameserver with this setup will the mail server be uninterrupted?  We can't afford much downtime at all for email.

One thing I have noticed is the IP in one TXT entry refers to our old (current) servers IP which of course needs changing, but will this break the email in any way if I just modify that entry?  For example, does Google need to be notified of this change at all or will it happily just pick up the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things.

1. The TXT record is in fact an SPF record, stating that the two IPv4 addresses `84.45.57.143` and `84.45.57.142`, as well as the A record for the domain itself, are allowed sender hosts. Validation of all email from any other hosts with your sender domain, should result in `SoftFail` (meaning "probably"/"possibly" SPAM). So if you plan to migrate a mail solution from the old server(s), you definitely want to update this.
2. You might want to check with google if you need to go through the [domain verification](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60216) process again, I think that's what the `google45673f3fa15785f3` record has been used for earlier. I don't think you need to do this when you move to a new Name Server, but better safe than sorry

Comment: Google only verifies the domain once, you can remove the txt record with no issues.